# How to display single product details in e-commerce website with React-js React-Router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, e-commerce

I am creating an e-commerce website, I want to make a feature, where if the user clicks on a particular product, the user should be able to see the product details of that particular product. I want to implement this in react js with react-router dom, how should I pass the id and show the details of the particular product

```
import "./HomeFurniture.scss";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import jsonData from '../../data.json';
import ProductCardContainer from '../../Component/Products/ProductCardContainer';
import TopHead from '../../Component/TopHead/TopHead';
import CustomSelect from '../../Component/TopHead/CustomSelect';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HiShoppingBag } from "react-icons/hi2";

const Bedroom = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('AtoZ');
  const [category1Data, setCategory1Data] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const bedroomProducts = jsonData.product.filter(product => product.category === 'Bedroom');

    if (selectedOption === 'AtoZ') {
      bedroomProducts.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
    } else if (selectedOption === 'ZtoA') {
      bedroomProducts.sort((a, b) => b.title.localeCompare(a.title));
    } else if (selectedOption === 'PriceLowToHigh') {
      bedroomProducts.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price.replace('$', '')) - parseFloat(b.price.replace('$', '')));
    } else if (selectedOption === 'PriceHighToLow') {
      bedroomProducts.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.price.replace('$', '')) - parseFloat(a.price.replace('$', '')));
    }

    setCategory1Data(bedroomProducts);
  }, [selectedOption]);

  const totalProductCards = category1Data.length;
  const homeLink = <Link to="/">HOME</Link>;
  const collectionlink = <Link to="/">Collection</Link>;
  const bedroomLink = <Link to="/bedroom">Bedroom</Link>;

  return (
    <div className='furniture'>
      <TopHead
        tophead="Bedroom"
        links={[homeLink, collectionlink, bedroomLink]}
      />
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='top-bed'>
          <p className='furniture_header'>Showing {totalProductCards} products</p>
          <CustomSelect selectedOption={selectedOption} setSelectedOption={setSelectedOption} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='container'>
        {totalProductCards > 0 ? (
          <div className="row">
            {category1Data.map((item, index) => (
              <ProductCardContainer
                key={index}
                title={item.title}
                description={item.description}
                description2={item.description2}
                price={item.price}
                img={item.img}
                sku={item.sku}
                availability={item.availability}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="no-product ">
            <HiShoppingBag className='shopping-bag' />
            <p>There are no products!</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Bedroom;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GoGitCompare } from "react-icons/go";
import { AiOutlineHeart, AiFillHeart } from "react-icons/ai";
import { BsArrowsFullscreen, BsPlus, BsDash } from "react-icons/bs";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

const ProductCardContainer = (props) => {
    const [isInWishlist, setIsInWishlist] = useState(false);
    const [isInCompare, setIsInCompare] = useState(false);
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
    const [counte, setCounte] = useState(0);

    const toggleWishlist = () => {
        setIsInWishlist(!isInWishlist);

        if (!isInWishlist) {
            toast.success('Added to wishlist!', {
                position: 'top-right',
                autoClose: 2000,
            });
        } else {
            toast.error('Removed from wishlist!', {
                position: 'top-right',
                autoClose: 2000,
            });
        }
    };

    const toggleCompare = () => {
        setIsInCompare(!isInCompare);
        if (!isInCompare) {
            toast.success('Added to Compare!', { position: 'top-right', autoClose: 2000 });
        } else {
            toast.error('Removed from Compare!', { position: 'top-right', autoClose: 2000 });
        }
    };

    const incrementeCount = () => { setCounte(counte + 1) };
    const decrementtCount = () => {
        if (counte > 0) {
            setCounte(counte - 1);
        } else {
            alert("0 aavi gyo chee..")
        }
    };

    const handleMouseEnter = () => {
        setIsHovered(true);
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        setIsHovered(false);
    };
    // const formattedTitle = props.id.replace(/ /g, '-');
    const truncatedTitle = props.title.length > 26 ? `${props.title.substring(0, 26)}...` : props.title;

    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-ld-4 col-sm-6">
                <div
                    className={`product-card ${isHovered ? 'hovered' : ''}`}
                    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
                    onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}>
                    <Card>
                        <div className='svg-icons'>
                            <span id="heart" className="heart" onClick={toggleWishlist}>
                                {isInWishlist ? <AiFillHeart /> : <AiOutlineHeart />}
                            </span>
                            {isHovered && (
                                <span className='button-svg'>
                                    <BsArrowsFullscreen onClick={() => setModalShow(true)} />
                                    <GoGitCompare onClick={toggleCompare} />
                                </span>
                            )}
                        </div>
                        {isHovered && (
                            <button className='form-btn-cart' onClick={toggleWishlist}>
                                {isInWishlist ? "Remove From Cart" : "Add To Cart"}
                            </button>
                        )}
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={props.img} />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Link to={`/product/${props.title}`} onClick={() => openProductDetail(props)}>
                                <h4>{props.price}</h4>
                                <Card.Title>{truncatedTitle}</Card.Title>
                            </Link>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    <ToastContainer />
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Modal */}
            <Modal show={modalShow} onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                size="lg"
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                centered>
                <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <div className="model-box">
                        <img src={props.img} alt={props.title} />
                        <div className="model-detail">
                            <p><strong>SKU : </strong> {props.sku}</p>
                            <p><strong>Availability : </strong>{props.availability}</p>
                            <h4>{props.title}</h4>
                            <p className='price'>{props.price}</p>
                            <p className='model-description'>{props.description}</p>
                            <div className="model-button">
                                <div className="timenum">
                                    <button className="hookbtn" onClick={decrementtCount}><BsDash /></button>
                                    <p className="hookh1">{counte} </p>
                                    <button className="hookbtn" onClick={incrementeCount}><BsPlus /></button>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button type="button" className='model_cart'>Add To Cart</button>
                                </div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div className='model-svg-icons'>
                                    <span id="heart" className="heart" state={{ product: props }}>
                                        {isInWishlist ? <AiFillHeart /> : <AiOutlineHeart />}
                                        <p>Add To Wishlist</p>
                                    </span>
                                    <span id="heart" className="heart" onClick={toggleCompare}>
                                        <GoGitCompare />
                                        <p>Add To Compare</p>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
};

export default ProductCardContainer;
```

```
import React from "react"
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.scss"
import Navbar from "./Component/Navbar/Navbar";
import Footer from "./Component/Footer/Footer";
import About from "./Pages/About/About";
import Contact from "./Pages/Contact/Contact";
import Bedroom from "./Pages/Home-Furniture/Bedroom";
import Dining from "./Pages/Home-Furniture/Dining";
import Living from "./Pages/Home-Furniture/Living";
import HospitalBed from "./Pages/Hospital-Furniture/HospitalBed";
import HospitalUtility from "./Pages/Hospital-Furniture/HospitalUtility";
import Lounge from "./Pages/Office-Furniture/Lounge";
import OfficeChair from "./Pages/Office-Furniture/OfficeChair";
import OfficeTable from "./Pages/Office-Furniture/OfficeTable";
import Home from "./Pages/Home/Home";
import SingleProduct from "./Component/Products/SingleProduct";

function App() {

  const Layout = () => {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Navbar />
        <Outlet />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Layout />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/",
          element: <Home />
        },
        {
          path: "/about",
          element: <About />
        },
        {
          path: "/contact",
          element: <Contact />
        },
        {
          path: "/homefurniture/bedroom",
          element: <Bedroom />
        },
        {
          path: "/homefurniture/dining",
          element: <Dining />
        },
        {
          path: "/homefurniture/living",
          element: <Living />
        },
        {
          path: "/hospitalfurniture/hospitalbed",
          element: <HospitalBed />
        },
        {
          path: "/hospitalfurniture/hospitalutility",
          element: <HospitalUtility />
        },
        {
          path: "/officefurniture/lounge",
          element: <Lounge />
        },
        {
          path: "/officefurniture/officechair",
          element: <OfficeChair />
        },
        {
          path: "/officefurniture/officetable",
          element: <OfficeTable />
        },
        {
          path: `/product/:id`,
          element: <SingleProduct />
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </div>
    
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

singleproduct.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "../TopHead/TopHead.scss";
import "./SingleProduct.scss";
import jsonData from '../../data.json';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';
import { GoGitCompare } from "react-icons/go";
import { AiOutlineHeart, AiFillHeart } from "react-icons/ai";
import { BsPlus, BsDash } from "react-icons/bs";

const SingleProductPage = () => {
  const [isInWishlist, setIsInWishlist] = useState(false);
  const [counte, setCounte] = useState(0);

  const { productId } = useParams();
  const thisProduct = jsonData.product.find(prod => prod.id === productId);

  const toggleCompare = () => {
    setIsInCompare(!isInCompare);
    if (!isInCompare) {
      toast.success('Added to Compare!', { position: 'top-right', autoClose: 2000 });
    } else {
      toast.error('Removed from Compare!', { position: 'top-right', autoClose: 2000 });
    }
  };

  const incrementeCount = () => { setCounte(counte + 1) };
  const decrementtCount = () => {
    if (counte > 0) {
      setCounte(counte - 1);
    } else {
      alert("0 aavi gyo chee..")
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className='topheading'>
      <div className='top container-fluid'>
        <h2>{thisProduct.title}</h2>
        <ul>
          <li className='sc-jVKKMF dYETTy'>badroom</li>
          <li className='sc-jVKKMF dYETTy'>badroom</li>
          <li className='sc-jVKKMF dYETTy'>badroom</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom container">
        <div className="model-box">
          <img src="https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F11-02.jpg%3Fv%3D1632281991&w=384&q=75" />
          <div className="model-detail">
            <p><strong>SKU : </strong> </p>
            <p><strong>Availability : </strong></p>
            <h4>hgdkdnh fkwfwk</h4>
            <p className='price'>234</p>
            <p className='model-description'>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, natus placeat!
              Beatae cupiditate in sunt omnis quos eius repudiandae itaque velit eveniet quae ratione, unde placeat id nihil doloremque ipsum.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta at ipsum voluptate laboriosam quasi? Omnis laudantium repudiandae,
              quisquam debitis quaerat tempora velit sapiente fugiat modi ipsam perspiciatis tenetur magni saepe!
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur vel tempore ipsum minima doloribus dolore, assumenda corrupti illum
              magni suscipit error amet blanditiis eius, debitis perferendis. Quod earum amet eaque.</p>
            <div className="model-button">
              <div className="timenum">
                <button className="hookbtn" onClick={decrementtCount}><BsDash /></button>
                <p className="hookh1">{counte} </p>
                <button className="hookbtn" onClick={incrementeCount}><BsPlus /></button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button type="button" className='model_cart'>Add To Cart</button>
              </div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div className='model-svg-icons'>
                <span id="heart" className="heart">
                  {isInWishlist ? <AiFillHeart /> : <AiOutlineHeart />}
                  <p>Add To Wishlist</p>
                </span>
                <span id="heart" className="heart" onClick={toggleCompare}>
                  <GoGitCompare />
                  <p>Add To Compare</p>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="revi-des">
        <Tabs>
          <TabList>
            <Tab>
              Description
            </Tab>
            <Tab >
              Reviews
            </Tab>
          </TabList>

          <TabPanel>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi voluptates nemo fugit sit excepturi ipsum quod, maxime ea numquam, placeat qui ipsa aspernatur nobis possimus vitae ducimus totam. Praesentium, deserunt.</p>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi quod officiis laudantium? Quaerat quam modi laborum explicabo dicta quibusdam atque suscipit consequatur voluptatem amet eum accusamus incidunt quo, inventore ipsa.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam aut impedit sit in. Amet laudantium maiores modi sapiente similique possimus iure enim. Nemo minus tempore voluptatum laudantium temporibus totam in.

            </p>
          </TabPanel>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default SingleProductPage;
```

data.json

```
{
    "product": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category": "NewArrival",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Variable Product",
            "price": "$69.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F11-02.jpg%3Fv%3D1632281991&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category": "NewArrival",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Josefa Queen Size Bed with Storage in Natural Teak Wood Finish",
            "price": "$199.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F1.jpg%3Fv%3D1636862996&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "category": "NewArrival",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Minimalist Mid-Century Modern Style Bed",
            "price": "$159.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F2.jpg%3Fv%3D1632544899&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "category": "NewArrival",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Twist Dining Table",
            "price": "$49.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F1_d9913561-510c-4d82-8185-4e4fd3828742.jpg%3Fv%3D1632545251&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "category": "NewArrival",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Round Dining Table without chair",
            "price": "$79.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F2_bb835864-60d7-4be5-8e85-cfee7c9f784d.jpg%3Fv%3D1632545382&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "category": "NewArrival",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Hospital Reception Table",
            "price": "$129.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F1_6c997eeb-8f70-49d3-8432-0d82b2c83c8f.jpg%3Fv%3D1632547241&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "category": "NewArrival",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "High back lounge office chairs",
            "price": "$89.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F2_f43a8aeb-8572-4889-9c86-cc7914ee0649.jpg%3Fv%3D1632547434&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "category": "NewArrival",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Bedroom Exclusive Mattress",
            "price": "$99.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F3.jpg%3Fv%3D1632547635&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "category": "Featured",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Variable Product",
            "price": "$69.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F11-02.jpg%3Fv%3D1632281991&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "category": "Featured",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Twist Dining Table",
            "price": "$49.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F1_d9913561-510c-4d82-8185-4e4fd3828742.jpg%3Fv%3D1632545251&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "category": "Featured",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "High back lounge office chairs",
            "price": "$89.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F2_f43a8aeb-8572-4889-9c86-cc7914ee0649.jpg%3Fv%3D1632547434&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "category": "Featured",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Round Dining Table without chair",
            "price": "$79.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F2_bb835864-60d7-4be5-8e85-cfee7c9f784d.jpg%3Fv%3D1632545382&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "category": "OnSale",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Variable Product",
            "price": "$69.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F11-02.jpg%3Fv%3D1632281991&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "category": "OnSale",
            "sku": "GXW",
            "availability": "In Stock",
            "title": "Twist Dining Table",
            "price": "$49.0",
            "img": "https://furns-react.netlify.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0597%2F8970%2F5392%2Fproducts%2F2_bb835864-60d7-4be5-8e85-cfee7c9f784d.jpg%3Fv%3D1632545382&w=384&q=75",
            "description": " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dicta, culpa quidem commodi id itaque labore placeat atque voluptatem quos accusantium, natus rem molestiae illum non ullam esse ut! Magnam. ",
            
        },
```

How can I show the details of a single product on another page?

Comment: you can make an API which h fetch product detail when the user click on single product

Comment: Please show the `SingleProduct` component also

Comment: I have added singleproduct page and data.json file plz check

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are multiple options which you can pick.

1. To send the Id of the product using useNavigate hook from the list of product page and then accessing that id on that page using the useLocation hook. And then you can send that id into the backend which will give you the specific product details which then you can show it to the user by populating the value in react.
2. To send the whole object to the product details page using same useNavigate hook and in this case you won't be needing to put a request in the backend, as the data has came in the state only, through useNavigate. You can access the data again using useLocation.

here is the useful link if you want to use this approach

https://dev.to/esedev/how-to-pass-and-access-data-from-one-route-to-another-with-uselocation-usenavigate-usehistory-hooks-1g5m